# Linux kernel module strange behaviour

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am studying a linux kernel, so I try to write a simple modules.

The following code is supposed to control how many times `read()` for the `/proc/proc_test` is called:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/proc_fs.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <asm/current.h>

static int __init init(void);
static void __exit stop(void);
static int proc_read(char *buffer, char **start, off_t offset, int size, int *eof, void *data);

static int counter = 0;

static int proc_read(char *buffer, char **start, off_t offset, int size, int *eof, void *data) {
    if (size < 256) return -ENOMEM;
    return sprintf(buffer, "counter = %d\n", counter++); <-- supposed to be incremented once
}

static int __init init() {
    if (create_proc_read_entry("proc_test", 0, NULL, proc_read, NULL) == 0) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "Can not creat entry\n");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }
    printk("Entry created!\n");
    return 0;
}

static void __exit stop() {
    remove_proc_entry("proc_test", NULL);
    printk("Entry removed!\n");
    return;
}

module_init(init);
module_exit(stop);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

I am facing the issue that when I read from the `/proc/proc_test/` using `cat` or `tail`, the counter is incremented by 3 instead of by 1.

Output:

```
cat /proc/proc_test 
counter = 0

cat /proc/proc_test 
counter = 3

cat /proc/proc_test 
counter = 6
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12354224/912144) has a good hint, I have been having this issue too. Setting `*eof = 1` theoretically should have solved the problem but somehow it doesn't.

My fix was to **also** add this on the top of the function:

```
if (offset > 0)    // even though I set *eof = 1, the kernel is still calling me, so return 0 for it to stop
    return 0;
```

The comment above is in fact what I had written in my own module.

What this does is to make sure only the first call to your function (in which `offset` is 0) does anything.

Comment: It seems to be a solution. Anyway I should be more careful for `read()` calls.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
static int proc_read(char *buffer, char **start, off_t offset, int size, int *eof, void *data) {
    if (size < 256) return -ENOMEM;
    int count= sprintf(buffer, "counter = %d\n", counter++);
    *eof = 1;
    return count;
}
```

setting *eof=1, your driver informs the kernel (and the application which want to read your proc file) that your driver reached EOF.

Comment: what happens if u want to read the data using dd (get 100 bytes at once): $ dd if=/proc/proc_test of=test.out bs=100 count=1

Comment: dd: reading `/proc/proc_test': Cannot allocate memory
0+0 records in
0+0 records out
0 bytes (0 B) copied, 0.000511612 s, 0.0 kB/s

Answer (score 3):

The only thing wrong is that you have an unreasonable expectation. What makes you think `cat /proc/proc_test` will only call `read` once?

```
$ strace cat /proc/self/stat | grep read
read(3, "17423 (cat) R 17420 17420 13224 "..., 32768) = 238
read(3, "", 32768)                      = 0
$
```

Comment: It counts the `read` syscalls performed on the pseudofile that the module creates, not all reads performed by the process. Although correct, your sample shows reading from a different file with the same descriptor ID (probably closed and then opened anew between the first and the second `read` calls), not only `/proc/self/stat`, and could be a bit misleading.

Comment: @HristoIliev: Corrected. Thanks. My point is only that expecting one read at that point is unreasonable.

Comment: I found that `cat` really calls `read()` twice (checked it by the current->pid and current->comm output with `printk()`), so thanks for the issue explanation. Is there a better way to prevent increment than in Shahbaz's answer? And how can I to find out who calls `read()` third time?